# Rails, Heroku, Scheduler, & Mailgun: Mail not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mailgun

Strange issue. I have a rake task in scheduler.rake:

```
task :send_daily_digests => :environment do
  User.where(frequency: "daily").each do |user|
    user.send_digest("daily")
  end
end
```

User.rb has a method:

```
def send_digest(frequency)
    if frequency == "daily"
      NotificationMailer.send_daily_digest(self.id).deliver_now
    elsif frequency == "weekly"
      NotificationMailer.send_weekly_digest(self.id).deliver_now
    end
  end
```

And I've setup the daily task in scheduler in heroku:

```
rake send_daily_digests
```

However, when I look in my Mailgun logs after a few days, I can see that no mail has been sent. If I manually call the rake task in the console `heroku run rake send_daily_digests` then I can see the mail is being sent and it shows up in the mailgun logs.

I double checked heroku scheduler and it says the rake task has been running every day.

Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: What is the output of `heroku logs --ps scheduler.1`? (assuming this is the first).

Comment: I don't get any output

Comment: This is a problem with the configured scheduler than.  The scheduled task has yet to run (given the no output). Delete it and recreate it maybe?  Make sure you specify a time and it is the correct app by using `heroku addons:open scheduler` from the same place you ran heroku logs